# How to keep params in url when clicked from one component to another component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, frontend, router

http://localhost:3000/ansiklopediler/1

I wanna see 
http://localhost:3000/ansiklopediler/1/kitapdetaylari/8

instead of this
http://localhost:3000/kitapdetaylari/8

when I chose a book in my URL.

How can I obtain this in my URL

in my App.js

also, I am taking id from URL to get books from API

Comment: my App.js is <Route path="/ansiklopediler/:dosyaId?"  component={Ansiklopediler} />

<Route path="/:kitapdetaylari/:dosyaId?" component={KitapDetay} />

Comment: Do you want `http://localhost:3000/ansiklopediler/1/kitapdetaylari/8` as the final URL?

Comment: Are you using react-router?

Comment: i am using react-router-dom and yes ı wanna see http://localhost:3000/ansiklopediler/1/kitapdetaylari/8 in my url

Comment: Please add code of your router file and component

Answer (score 0):

Please put your code whatever you have done in question or try following =>

In Router file add Route =>

```
<Route exact path='/ansiklopediler/:ansiklopedilerId/kitapdetaylari/:kitapdetaylariId' component={kitapdetaylari} />
// kitapdetaylari = your kitapdetaylari Component
```

to navigate =>

```
function Topics({ match }) {
    return (
      <div>
            <Link to={`${match.url}/kitapdetaylari/${kitapdetaylariId}`}>kitapdetaylariBooks</Link>
      </div>
    );
    // match.url = active url
    // kitapdetaylariId = your kitapdetaylariId
    // when you click on above Link you will get something like http://localhost:3000/ansiklopediler/1/kitapdetaylari/8 this if your active route is http://localhost:3000/ansiklopediler/1
}
```